# google app engine flexible - How to start an existing version using client library or REST API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an application that consists of two services, a) frontend code running in app engine standard, and b) backend code which runs under app engine flexible.

App engine flexible is more expensive than app engine standard, and the code running there doesn't need to run all of the time.

I want to be able to start and stop version of the backend service b from python code running in the frontend service a.

How can I do this? I have found some app engine api documentation here, but there doesn't seem to be a way to create an instance from a version:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Engine Flexible does not scale to zero instances. The minimum number of instances is 1.

App Engine Flexible runs your code in a container. If your code is stateless or stores its state elsewhere, consider Google Cloud Run. Cloud Run scales to zero and runs similar containers to Flexible with much lower cost. Cloud Run will automatically scale down to zero and scale up to thousands of instances.

Comment: You can't have 0 instances but you can "stop" a flex version on the console.  Though I'm pretty sure there is no API to stop and start a flex version so it doesn't provide a solution for the question.

Comment: @gaefan that's what made me hope there was a way to do it, but when I try to restart stopped instances manually it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks @john-hanley. It seems to do the job, but unfortunately not available in my region. Any idea when it will be out of beta?

Comment: A release date has not been published yet. Google prefers to be in beta for a while to make sure that all the corner cases are tested. There will be a new region or two soon - as in weeks.